# Existing .plist and .ipa files returning 404 with Godaddy?

Tags: http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I am trying to distribute an app OTA on my website. I have a plist file (Manifest) hosted here: http://www.codepixl.net/MathHelper/app.plist Except EVEN THOUGH it is there, it returns a 404 when you go to it in a browser... Why is this happening? I am using Plesk (Windows) Hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add the MIME types for the files in my server settings:

```
application/xml .plist
application/octet .ipa
```